# Auto hiding an image's left and right sides according to the browser width

Tags: image, width

So my image is 1920px x 150px
all I want is the image should remain at the center of the screen when the browser screen bocomes lessthan 1920px, it should auto hide an equal amount of pixels from left and right sides of the image.

eg., if the browser total width is 1520px, then 200px from left and 200px from right should be hidden (I don't want the image to be at the center allways)

Is there some way i can do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show some tries, some code please.

Comment: If your image is directly in the <body> tag, you can simply style your image with some css `.img_class { margin: 0 auto }`. If it's inside some other div etc, you can center it within that div, or use a fixed positioning for the image and then use margin auto.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but,
making it to the center is so easy i know. But, when the screen size decreases, i want the image still in center and cutout the rest of pixels from both sides..!

Comment: @user2158052 if you do it the CSS way, it will respond to screen resizes automatically. Of course, if the image does not fit into the page, adding `html,body{overflow:hidden}` should hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the image in an `<IMG>` tag, use it as the `background` of a `div`, give it a class `imgBG`, and include these styles:

```
.imgBG{
background: url(images/imagename.jpg) no-repeat 50% top;
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
margin: auto;
}
```